# iTunes version in AppStore download of Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, itunes

What version of iTunes comes with current AppStore download of Mountain Lion?  10.7?  11.0?

**UPDATE:**
As of today (6-Dec-2013), AppStore has 10.8.5 with iTunes 11.0.1.

Was hoping to avoid a whole VM install to find out the iTunes version, but it had to happen.  Will keep looking for a table view, and will post it here if I find one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the versions of OS X currently available from App Store, but my 10.8.0 VM has iTunes 10.6.3 and my 10.9.0 VM has iTunes 11.1. I created the 10.8 VM from an installer that I downloaded from App Store about a year ago.